# How do i generate an index number to display in the template

Tags: django

This might be a very simple question but i'm very new to django

So i'm working on Django book list app and i need to have an index for each book in order. i was using `id` that was generated by the database at first but then i realized the number jumps from 3 to 10 cause i was deleting some books earlier. How do i generate an index number for every object in the `queryset` in order?

Here's my views just incase

```
def booklist_view(request):
    
  queryset = Book.objects.all()
  bkff = BookListForm()
  
  if request.method == 'POST':

      bkff = BookListForm(request.POST)

      if bkff.is_valid():
         
          bkff.save()
          bkff = BookListForm()

  context = {
      'form': bkff,
      'arrayobj': queryset,
      'index': 0
      
     
  }
  return render(request, 'booklist1st/booklist.html', context)
```

and here's my HTML

```
 {% for ins in arrayobj %}
        
        <div class="data" id="test">
            <div class="num"><p>{{ins.id}}</p></div>
            <div class="title"><p>{{ins.title}}</p></div>
            <div class="author"><p>{{ins.author}}</p></div>
            <div class="ISBN"><p>{{ins.isbn}}</p></div>
            <div class="edit"><a href="#">Edit</a></div>
            <div class="delete"><a href="#">Delete</a></div>
            
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`forloop.counter`**--(Django doc)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#for) as

```
{% for ins in arrayobj %}
    {{ forloop.counter }}
    {{ ins.title }}
{% endfor %}
```